# Recurring Payment using paypal REST API

Tags: payment-gateway

I have a website where I need to implement recurring payments. I have implemented [Paypal Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) in a project earlier, but I can not find option of recurring payment option as in the PayPal REST API docs.

While I was googling, I found few people suggesting to store [credit card](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/) in paypal and write a cron job that will charge the card accordingly. But I am not sure is it the clean way to implement the gateway.

Also, some people suggested to use the classic recurring API.

Please suggest me the right path and points that I should take care while implementing recurring payment. (BTW I am using RoR)

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to be storing credit card data locally - then you're responsible for a very broad PCI compliance scope.

PayPal offers a functionality called ARB - Automatic Recurring Billing, which helps you with recurring payments. You may also want to look at [Recurly](http://recurly.com) (where I work), which handles the credit card storage and recurring billing functionalities.

Comment: I would go directly with Recurly, BrainTree or Stripe. PayPal are better only if you want global reach.

Comment: @Rachel : I will not be storing the credit card loacally, it will be stored in PayPal DB. I will access the card with `credit_card_id`.